# Xcode command line tools not finding header files (Catalina Update 10.15.7)

Tags: c++, c, xcode, gcc, g++

Recently I have updated my MacBook operating system to Catalina 10.15.7 and Xcode command line tools to 12.1. Ever since I have been getting the following error when I try to use any C++ compiler:

```
gcc A3v2.cpp
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/ios:38,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from A3v2.cpp:13:
/usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/cwchar:44:10: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
   44 | #include <wchar.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I have tried removing and re installing command line tools but it hasn't worked (amongst trying various other solutions I've found on Stackoverflow). When I run sudo find on wchar.h I get the following.

```
sudo find /Library -name wchar.h
find: /Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC: Operation not permitted
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h
```

As a current work around (as I need a c++ compiler for a current assignment) I have been using:

```
/usr/bin/gcc A3v2.cpp
```

however I'm hoping this will just be temporary. I think this is a path problem since the missing header file exsits? Not sure what I am doing when it comes to specifying file paths so please let me know if you know how to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: `/usr/local`? Is that a homebrew installation perhaps? What's the output of `which gcc`? Also, what happens if instead of `gcc` you use `clang++` to compile C++ sources?

Comment: Not home-brew as far as I know. I could have done something stupid when tired and trying to get other things to work.

clang++ works fine

`$which gcc
/usr/local/bin/gcc`

Comment: macOS will never install anything in `/usr/local`, so that looks like you installed some sort of toolchain yourself there. The output of `ls -l /usr/local` would be required to see if you indeed installed homebrew or not. If it is homebrew, you can uninstall it: https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew

Comment: Also, when using homebrew, `gcc` and `g++` will not refer to `clang` and `clang++` anymore, but to the homebrew-provided installation of GCC. It's best to use `clang`/`clang++` anyway, since xcode uses Clang, not GCC. The `gcc` and `g++` aliases it provides are only there for backwards compatibility, and as you've noticed, they're not even aliases anymore if you install GCC into `/usr/local`.

Comment: Okay thank you.

`drwxr-xr-x  45 root  wheel  1440 17 Oct 12:04 bin
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel   320 17 Oct 12:04 include
drwxr-xr-x  89 root  wheel  2848 17 Oct 12:04 lib
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel    96 20 May  2018 libexec
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel    96 26 Sep  2018 remotedesktop
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel   320 14 Oct  2019 share`

Here is the output for `ls -l /usr/local`

How would I know if I installed home-brew from that output?